# graphically browse s-expression output from antlr4

Tags: antlr

Is there a way to take the S-Expression output from Antlr4 and display it graphically as a treeview in Windows 10?

here's my grammar file for antlr4:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/vhdl/vhdl.g4

here's my vhdl program to parse with antrl4:

```vhdl
entity testbench is

end entity;

architecture beh of testbench is
begin

end architecture;
```

Here's my S-Expression Output from Antlr4 for the vhdl file:

```
(design_file (design_unit context_clause (library_unit (primary_unit 
(entity_declaration entity 
(identifier testbench) is entity_header entity_declarative_part end entity ;))))
(design_unit context_clause (library_unit 
(secondary_unit (architecture_body architecture (identifier beh) of 
(identifier testbench) is architecture_declarative_part 
begin architecture_statement_part end architecture ;)))) <EOF>)
```

I want to see the s-expression output from antlr in a treeview with collapable nodes, something like this:

[image: ast explorer]

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/treeview-control-in-C-Sharp/

Is there a windows 10 program for graphically browsing the s-expressions output of antrl4 as a graphical treeview?

Ideally I want something that reads the antrl s-expressions generated by -tree flag, and the tokens list generated by -tokens flag, and merges them together for display in a GUI treeview so that when i click on a node of the s-expression in the tree and i get the information in the token file as well...

Comment: There's likely nothing to view Antlr's [ToStringTree()](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/Trees.html#toStringTree(org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.Tree)) "s-expression". And, complicating things, one could interpret `(name a b c)` as a node named "name" with children "a", "b", and "c", as with Antlr's "s-expression"; or, it could be an unnamed node with children "name", "a", "b", "c"; or a chain of binary tree nodes (see wiki s-expr). The semantics are not well-defined. I would output the tree as an XML or JSON expression, and use one of the ubiquitous online viewers.

Comment: What you call an "s-expression" (never heard this term before) is the parse tree in LISP format. There are several tools which can show the parse tree graphically. But I know none which shows it in the particular way you want it.

Comment: @MikeLischke S-expressions are how LISP people describe what everybody else just thinks of as "LISP syntax".  Weirdly, LISP was originally supposed to be written in a different syntax, called M-expressions.  It just never really happened.

Answer (score 2):

For Java target, use `Trees.inspect(tree, parser)`. It'll pop up a window with the tree view.  Or use [Intellij/jetbrains plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4)